# explanation on bitwise operators

Tags: c, networking, bitwise-operators

I found this piece of code online and it works as part of my project, but I'm not sure why. I don't want to just use it without understanding what it does.

```
type = (packet_data[12] << 8) | packet_data[13];
```

if I use it I get the proper type (0x0800 for IPv4) and can use it for comparison on printing out whether it's IPv4 or IPv6. If I don't use it and try something like:

```
if(packet_data[12] == 08 && packet_data[13] == 00)
    print out IPv4
```

it doesn't work (compiling errors).

Also if I just print out the values like

```
printf"%02X", packet_data[12];
printf"%02X", packet_data[13];
```

it prints out the proper value in the form 0800, but I need to print out that it's an IPv4 type. Which is why I need to comparison in the first place. Thanks for any piece of advice or explanation on what this does would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Always show *what errors you get*

Comment: `08` is invalid as it is an octal prefix with 8 in it. `0x800` is hexadecimal

Comment: `if(packet_data[12] == 0x8 && packet_data[13] == 0)` would work

Comment: The integer literal `08` is invalid. Integer numbers starting with `0` are [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers, for which digits go from `0` to `7` (inclusive). [Any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told you that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I am willing to bet that most _beginners_ books do not mention it at all, including those in the list you linked.  I am not sure that makes them _not good_, but if you believe that, then the list is perhaps not a good suggestion.  The one available for free in the beginners list of the highest scoring answer does not for example.  Most occasions I have seen octal literals used in C code it was by accident and was the cause of bugs and errors such as this.  The octal notation itself is hardly a subject for beginners, so I would not expect it to be covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(packet_data[12] == 08 && packet_data[13] == 00)
```

the right literal operands are seen as octal base literals by the compiler.

Fortunately for you, `8` cannot represent an octal number and you're getting a compilation error.

You mean hexadecimal literals:

```
if (packet_data[12] == 0x8 && packet_data[13] == 0x0)
```

this line:

```
(packet_data[12] << 8) | packet_data[13]
```

recreates the big endian value (network convention) of the data located at offsets 12 & 13. Both are equivalent in your case, although the latter is more convenient to compare values as a whole.

Comment: aaaah ok thank you very much, so the first line that I wasn't sure about type = (packet_data[12] << 8) | packet_data[13] does that for me? (converts the hexadecimal into an int). I looked up the << operator and it's bitwise operator, but not sure why that's used in the example I saw. Also why is there an | (or) symbol between them. Then it stores the results in type which I can compare as if(type == 0x0800)

Comment: yes, exactly. it rebuilds the value from MSB & LSB (big endian)

Comment: @Mike1982 : No - it does not *"converts the hexadecimal into an int"* - there is no hexadecimal.  It packs two 8 bit integers into a single 16 bit integer.  To do that you move the most-significant byte to the upper 8 bits, and the least into the lower.  The `|` is the bitwise-or operator.  In this case you could also use the arithmetic `+` as it happens, but that might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
type = (packet_data[12] << 8) | packet_data[13];
```

The `<<` is bitwise shift left. It takes the binary representation of the variable and shifts its 1's to the left, 8 bits in this case.

'0x0800' looks like `100000000000` in binary. So in order for 0x0800 to be the type, it has to end up looking like that after `| packet_data[13]`. This last part is bitwise OR. It will write a 1 if either the left side or the right side have a 1 in that place and a 0 otherwise.

So after shifting the value in packet_data[12], the only way for it to be type 0x0800 (`100000000000`) is if packet_data[13] looks like 0x0800 or 0x0000:

```
type = (0x800)  <==>  ( 100000000000 | 100000000000 )
type = (0x800)  <==>  ( 100000000000 | 000000000000 )
```

Also, to get the `0x` out from printf() you need a to add the `%#` format specifier. But to get 0x0800 you need to specify a `.04` which means 4 characters including leading zeros. However this won't output the `0x` if the type is 0. For that you'd need to hardcode the literal `0x` into printf().

```
printf("%#02x\n", data);
printf("%#.04x\n", data);
printf("0x%.04x\n", data=0);
```

### Output

```
0x800
0x0800
0x0000
```

Comment: ok thank you very much for the explanation. That cleared it up

Answer (score 0):

`packet_data[12] << 8` takes the first Ethertype octet and shifts it 8 bits to the left to the upper 8 bits of a 16-bit word.

`| packet_data[13]` takes the second Ethertype octet and bitwise-ORs it to the previous 16-bit word.

You can then compare it to `0x0800` for IPv4 or `0x86DD` for IPv6; see a more complete list on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType#Examples

As has already been pointed out `08` doesn't work since numerals starting with `0` represent octal numbers, and `8` doesn't exist in octal.